# How can I debug my non-working HackerRank code?

Tags: java, algorithm

I failed a code test at a problem that should be very simple. But still, after submitting an incorrect solution, I cannot spot where my logic is going wrong. I want to learn from this let down so I can do better next time, but there is no solution online to this problem.

Is there an issue with my logic?

I passed 2/8 test cases, but the ones I failed had massive inputs or hidden inputs that I could not debug. My logic appeared to work for cases I could trace out by hand.

[image: Problem and my solution]

My solution's code below:

```
public static int efficientJanitor(List<Float> weight)
{
    int trips = 0;
    int currIndex = 0;
    float currWeight = 0;

    //Loop until we hit end of List
    while (currIndex < weight.size())
    {
        System.out.println("currIndex weight is: " + weight.get(currIndex));
        currWeight = currWeight + weight.get(currIndex);

        //If we still have room in the current bag
        if (currWeight < 3.00)
        {
            currIndex++;
        }

        //We have no more room in the bag, increment trips, DONT increment 
        //currIndex so that we add weight at currIndex
        //in next loop's iteration.

        else if (currWeight >= 3.00)
        {
            trips++;
            System.out.println("Trips is: " + trips);
            currWeight = 0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("currWeight is: " + currWeight);
    //Possible to have another bag left after while loop terminates,
    //since loop could end without handling any 
    //remaining weight

    if (currWeight >= 1.01 && currWeight <= 3.00)
    {
        trips++;
    }

    return trips; 
}
```

Comment: can you paste the question here, it is too difficult to read from image.

Comment: even for input `1.01,1.99,2.5,1.5,1.01` the code returns 4 , which is wrong, it should return 3.

Comment: What does your program output for n = 2 and weights = [2.5, 2.5]? I believe 2 would be the correct answer. I suspect that your algorithm is too simple and that you will need another one. Next try n = 6 and weights 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4. Correct answer is 3, I think.

Comment: Can you link to the hackerrank problem?

Comment: Is it an ongoing test or a interview test?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are using **greedy** algorithm that fails, for example, in such case: `[1.3 3 1.3 3]` giving 4 trips while 3 possible.

Try to sort weight list. Then for the smallest item find the largest possible pair item. Repeat with the second item and so on. *(two-index approach looks fine here)*

So `[1.1 1.4 1.45 1.5 1.9 2 2.5]` gives pairs `1.1+1.9` and `1.4 +1.5`

Comment: Very nice level of explanation. The questioner asked for help to learn what went wrong, and you’re providing exactly that without solving the problem for him or her.